# HEX RGB color manipulation methods?

Tags: language-agnostic, colors, hex, rgb

Here is my situation:

I've got a file consisting of some 100 color variables (set in HEX values, like `#FFFFFF`) - let's consider that a **Theme**.

Now what I want to do is:

- Apply the same set of attributes to ALL variables and have them changed accordingly
- e.g. Invert all colors (turn `#FFFFFF` to `#000000`, and so on...)

What I want to know is:

- Are there such methods/formulas for HEX RGB Manipulation already available?
- Could you point me to a (as much as possible) **complete** list of manipulations? (darken, lighten, multiply, invert, whatever - the more the better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do question 2 first:

### List of Color Operations

I think your best bet here is to scour the web for "Color Manipulation Library", and not care what OS/platform/application/tool shows up -- just check the docs for what things their API exposes. Here's what I found:

- [Color manipulation in Sass](http://nex-3.com/posts/89-powerful-color-manipulation-with-sass)

  - adjust-hue
  - saturate
  - desaturate
  - lighten
  - darken
  - grayscale
  - complement
  - mix (interesting! like mixing paint colors)
  - opacify
  - fade-in
  - fade-out
  - transparentize
- [Ruby color tools](http://ruby-pdf.rubyforge.org/color-tools/doc/index.html)

  (some of the above, plus...)

  - adjust_brightness
  - adjust_hue
  - adjust_saturation
  - darken_by
  - lighten_by
- [Color, Javascript color library](https://github.com/qix-/color)

  (again, ignoring what's already above...)

  - clearer
  - opaquer
  - rotate (ie, rotating through the color space, I think)
- [Grapefruit, Python color library](http://code.google.com/p/grapefruit/)

  Annoyingly, their docs can be [downloaded](http://code.google.com/p/grapefruit/downloads/detail?name=htmldoc-grapefruit-0.1a3.tar.gz) but are not hosted online.

  - ColorWithAlpha
  - ColorWithWhiteRef
  - ColorWithHue
  - ColorWithSaturation
  - ColorWithLightness
  - WebSafeDither

So that's a good handful of operations to start with.
Couldn't find one for Objective-C, sorry.

### Formulas for those Operations

The bad news: couldn't find one place that just had a nice cheat-sheet of formulas.

The good news: almost all of those libraries above are open source. I'm sure you could take a peek around and figure out how `ColorWithWhiteRef` actually works.

Good luck!

Comment: Whoa! That looks like a great answer full of resources; pretty much what I wanted. Give me some time to go through them carefully and I'll get back to you! Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)

Comment: For Cocoa, have a look at the `NSColor` docs. You can easily go from a hex string to an `NSColor` and vice versa, just search here for relevant questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a javascript library, the [xolor library](https://github.com/fresheneesz/xolor) has quite a few color transformations and combinations:

Combinations of two colors:

- blend - Overlays one color over another where the first color has an opacity
- combine - Combines two colors with XOR
- add - additive mix of two colors
- subtractive - subtractive mix of two colors
- subtract - the subtraction of two colors (not the same as subtractive, non-standard color function)
- multiply - multiplicative mix of two colors
- average - average between two colors
- gradient - returns a color along a gradient between two colors

Related color:

- lightness - returns or changes the lightness level
- saturation - returns or changes the saturation
- hue - returns or changes the hue
- luminosity - returns the WCAG luminosity
- sepia filter
- inverse
- greyFilter - changes the color to a grayscale version

Lists of related colors:

- triad
- tetrad
- split complement
- monochromatic
- analogous
- schemeByDegrees - Create a set of any number of colors by passing in an array of any numbmer of hue angle deltas

Misc

- distance - gets a
- contrast - gets the WCAG contrast level between two colors